# Can I add additional frames to button ones?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, frames, simplebutton

I'm new in ActionScript3 and Flash.
I would know if in the button instance (in which there are Up, Over, Down and Clicked frames, relative to upState, overState and downState) can be added other frames to call with the same method.

I need something like this:

```
if(...){
Button.upState = Button.MyOwnFrame;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No I don't think you can.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into the [`SimpleButton`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/SimpleButton.html) class as it allows you to assign any `DisplayObject` to the different states `upState`, `overState`, `downState`, and `hitTestState`.

Here's the example from Adobe's API Reference:

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class SimpleButtonExample extends Sprite {
        public function SimpleButtonExample() {
            var button:CustomSimpleButton = new CustomSimpleButton();
            addChild(button);
        }
    }
}

import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.display.Shape;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;

class CustomSimpleButton extends SimpleButton {
    private var upColor:uint   = 0xFFCC00;
    private var overColor:uint = 0xCCFF00;
    private var downColor:uint = 0x00CCFF;
    private var size:uint      = 80;

    public function CustomSimpleButton() {
        downState      = new ButtonDisplayState(downColor, size);
        overState      = new ButtonDisplayState(overColor, size);
        upState        = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, size);
        hitTestState   = new ButtonDisplayState(upColor, size * 2);
        hitTestState.x = -(size / 4);
        hitTestState.y = hitTestState.x;
        useHandCursor  = true;
    }
}

class ButtonDisplayState extends Shape {
    private var bgColor:uint;
    private var size:uint;

    public function ButtonDisplayState(bgColor:uint, size:uint) {
        this.bgColor = bgColor;
        this.size    = size;
        draw();
    }

    private function draw():void {
        graphics.beginFill(bgColor);
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0, size, size);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```